# Call function in a static library without implementation

Tags: c, static-libraries

I'd like to know if it's possible, within a static library, call a function that the implementation is in my application instead of in the library.

Like this:

***Static Library***

**foo.h**

```
void foo_func();
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo_func()
{
    app_func();
}
```

***Application***

**main.c**

```
#include <foo.h>

uint8_t flag = FALSE;

uint8 main()
{
    foo_func();

    while(!flag);

    return 0;
}

void app_func()
{
     flag = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Hey, is it so hard to test?

Comment: It is, but it's also a very bad way of setting things up. Tell us about your real problem.

Comment: Better to have the application pass a function pointer to the library at runtime.  Then it'll work with a dynamic library too.

Answer (score 1):

A static library created with `ar` is just an archive of `.o` object files. You can call any external functions in static library created with `ar`, present or not, like with any `.o` file. While it is possible, calling back the application is may be not the best design choice.

Comment: Why is this a bad design choice?